# HTML select element type is 'select-one' when jQuery is included. Is it a cross browser value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

When I alerted the type of a select element in JavaScript it displayed 'select-one'. But I thought it would display an empty string.

```
alert(document.getElementById('catsel').type) 
// where catsel is a select box. it displayed select-one
```

I tested this in Firefox 3.0.0.10

Is it a cross browser value? I have never used this property until now. I just want to know whether the value select-one is the same in all browsers.

Besides I am using jQuery in my page. When I searched throughout the project for the string "select-one" matches were found in jquery.js. So I conclude that when the page had loaded jQuery is setting a property 'type' to the select elements. Am I right?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `type` property is actually a DOM property native to form input elements, and doesn't have anything to do with jQuery - you can quickly corroborate this by running this on *any* website:

```
console.log(document.createElement('select').type);
```

For `select` elements, the two possible values it could take is `select-one` for normal select elements, ad `select-multiple` when more than one value is accepted (ie. when a valid `multiple` attribute is set).

The value should be cross-browser compatible - I could not find any information disputing this.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/select.type

Comment: Yes. haha. i wonder why i did not think of testing it before asking. oops. anyway. Thank you.