# check Element type for textarea,select-one,button is not working

Tags: jquery, vbscript

I'm converting vb script function to javascript.

`If oElement.type = "text" Or oElement.type = "textarea" Or oElement.type = "checkbox" Or oElement.type = "select-one" Or oElement.type = "button" Then`

I need to convert about vbscript line.when I use following solution it gives some script errors for 'textarea','select-one' and 'button'.this is working fine for 'text' and 'checkbox'.

```
  $("#frmOrder").children().each(function () {
    var child = $(this);
    // type checking for textarea,select-one,button is not working.
    if (child.is(":text") || child.is(":checkbox")) {
        if(Number(child.attr('tabindex')) >= nIndex) {
            child.attr('tabindex', child.attr('tabindex')+ <%=nChemIndexIncrement%>);
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me to solve this proble ?

Comment: Not tested, but `child.is('[type=checkbox]')` etc should work

Comment: yes. it works fine for checkbox, and text. but not work for 'textarea','select-one' and 'button'

Comment: this code works fine. when I check 'textarea','select-one' and 'button' one by one. it gave errors. but work fine for text and checkbox

Comment: show the code, ideally use jsfiddle.net. "does not work" is not helpful.

Comment: its a huge function with LOC of 200 lines. and page with more than 17000 lines.others are not depend on this unit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22521/discussion-between-madura-harshana-and-gerald-schneider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for valid css selectors, `:hover` or `first-child` are examples for these pseudo classes. `:checkbox` and `:text` do not exist. Try `input[type=text]` instead.

```
$("#frmOrder").children().each(function () {
    var child = $(this);
console.log(child);
    // type checking for textarea,select-one,button is not working.
    if (child.is("input[type=text]") || child.is("input[type=checkbox]") || child.is("textarea") || child.is("button") || child.is("input[type=button]")) {
        if(Number(child.attr('tabindex')) >= nIndex) {
            child.attr('tabindex', child.attr('tabindex')+ nChemIndexIncrement);
        }
    }
});
```

see this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKegv/

Comment: can I add `child.is("select-one")` also ?

Comment: I am not aware of a HTML element with the name `select-one`. Maybe this question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655125/html-select-element-type-is-select-one-when-jquery-is-included-is-it-a-cross

Comment: why did you check button for two times ?

Comment: for demonstration. And because you refused to post the code, so I had to make something up.

Comment: Can I use select with this, `child.is("input[type=select]")`